# How To Write A More Complex LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming I have:

```
public class Cluster
{
   List<Host>  HostList = new List<Host>();
}
public class Host
{
   List<VDisk> VDiskList = new List<VDisk>();
} 

public class VDisk
{
   public string Name {get; set}
}
```

I need all the hosts from a Cluster object that have a VDisk of a given name.  I can do it with a foreach but would rather have a LINQ query. I tried a SelectMany() but it is returning the VDisk and not the Hosts.   Do I need to implement a custom Comparer to do this?

Here's what I Tried:

```
Cluster CurrentCluster = new Cluster();

// add some hosts here

VDisk vdisk = new VDisk();
vdisk.Name="foo";
```

so now I want all the hosts that have a Vdisk named "foo"

this returns the vdisk, not the hosts:

```
CurrentCluster.Hosts.SelectMany(h => h.VDisks.Where(v => v.Name == vdisk.Name));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SelectMany` will indeed return the inner collections, flattened into one large collection.  You want your predicate to be on `Hosts`, not on `VDisks`, since what you're looking for is a list of `Hosts`.

This might work:

```
CurrentCluster.Hosts.Where(h => h.VDisks.Any(v => v.Name == vdisk.Name));
```

It basically says, "Return all hosts Where any of the VDisks match the condition `v.Name == vdisk.Name`.

I've also seen developers who don't know about `Any` write something like this:

```
CurrentCluster.Hosts.Where(h => h.VDisks.Count(v => v.Name == vdisk.Name) > 0);
```

Sometimes I feel there's a certain readability advantage to the latter, if one thinks that `Count` is a more intuitive name than `Any`.  Both should do the job, I just prefer the former.

Comment: Depending on what is in `Name` you may be better off with `v.Name.Equals(vDisk.Name,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`  @David Count will also enumerate the entire collection, where `Any` stops on the first matching predicate, so there can be performance advantages to using it over Count.

Comment: @David, thanks that worked.  I need something similar for a few other searches, so now I know know to do those too. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare `VDiskList` in `Host` as `public` or `internal`.

Then you can use this code:

```
var hostList = new List<Host>();
var givenVDiskName = "sample name";

var selectedHosts = (from h in hostList
                     where h.VDiskList.Any(vd => vd.Name == givenVDiskName)
                     select h).ToList();
```